Combobox performance issue
I have problem with comobobox performance. I have found similar question and it seems that it should work if I use spread on data, but it it's still takes a lot of time to load. It works when I am passing data as JSON and then parse, but I would prefer pass it as object. Am i doing something wrong? Enabling LWS is not an option.
Sorry, its kinda messy but i have tried to remove extra code, which is not related to question.
Apex
    public class ComponentWrapper {
    public class ComboboxOptions {
        @AuraEnabled public String value { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled public String label { get; set; }
    }

    @AuraEnabled public List<ComboboxOptions> options;
    }



    public class PicklistService {
    
        public static List<ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions> getOptions() {
            List<ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions> options = new List<ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions>();
    

            options.add(new ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions('1', '1'));
            options.add(new ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions('2', '2'));
            options.add(new ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions('3', '3'));
    
            return options;
        }
    }

    public class ComponentWrapperController {
        
        @AuraEnabled
        public static ComponentWrapper getOptions() {
            List<ComponentWrapper.ComboboxOptions> options = PicklistService.getOptions();
            
            ComponentWrapper wrapper = new ComponentWrapper();
            wrapper.options = options;
            
            return wrapper;
        }
    }

Parent
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getOptions from '@salesforce/apex/ComponentWrapperController.getOptions';

export default class ParentComponent extends LightningElement {
    data;
    error;  

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fetchOptions();
    }

    fetchOptions() {
        getOptions()
            .then((data) => {
                if (data) {
                    this.data = {...data};
                    this.error = undefined;
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                console.error('Error fetching options:', error);
            });
    }

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Label">
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <c-child-component data={data} ></c-child-component>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Child
<template>
    <lightning-combobox 
        label="Select"
        value={value}
        options={data.options}
        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildComponent extends LightningElement {
    _data;
    @api  set data(value); {
       this._data = {..data};
    }

}


You said enabling LWS is not an option, but did you try enabling it and seeing if performance improves? If it does, the bad news is that you might be out of options then.

The reason I say this is because I've had a similar issue when working on a component page for a managed package, and enabling LWS "fixed" it. In our case enabling LWS is an option, but we would also require subscribers of the solution to have it enabled to not suffer performance issues.

@RenatoOliveira I have tried and LWS fixes the issue. But why  copying data via spread doesn't fix performance? It the same issue as in linked question. And also I would rather  use JSON than LWS.

Given that this isn't documented anywhere in the Salesforce documentation, I wouldn't call it a fix. It was a way that some developers found to circumvent something that Salesforce's LWC service/compiler was doing back then, but now isn't anymore. You should probably review your "LWS is not an option" bit.

@RenatoOliveira you have a point, thanks. I would leave question as open for now if there are any other answers, but I will think about using lws.
